# AJAX post data from php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php file to validate a form with data that need to get sent through ajax.
The data that I receive back from the php file is unchanged, how can I receive the correct data?
main.js

```
$("#PersonForm").submit(function()
{ 
  var data = $("form").serializeArray();
  $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"main.php",
    act: 'validate',
    datatype:"json",
    data:data,
    function(data){
      console.log(data);
  }});

  return false;
});
```

main.php

```
else if ($_REQUEST['act'] == 'validate')
{
    $validateData = array();

    if (preg_match("[A-Za-z]{3,20}$/",$_REQUEST['name'])){
        $validateData['name'] = 1;
    }else{
        $validateData['name'] = 0;
    }

    echo json_encode($validateData);
```

The data that originally gets sent in the data array is name:Bob

The expected return is 1 or 0 but I recieve name:Bob back.

Comment: What is this doing? `$_REQUEST['act'] == 'validate'` does it ever enter this else if statement?

Comment: Yeah, what is the condition for the `if` statement on that?

Comment: I think that act is missing from the data that you post via ajax

Comment: if ($_REQUEST['act'] == 'default')
the default act and the one after enter no problem, just this validate act has issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the issue is you have to actually pass that in the `data`. You are doing this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"main.php",
    act: 'validate', // <--- THIS IS WRONG
    datatype:"json",
    data:data,       // <--- IT SHOULD BE IN THIS
    function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
});
```

It has to be in your `data` variable to be passed. You are using it as an option to the jQuery `ajax()` method, which doesn't work.

```
var data = $("form").serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'act', value: 'validate'});
// Then make ajax call here
```

After serializing your form data, you can add that on as an additional value.